# Better Way to Save js object State?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a product list which is like:

```
let products = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'pro1'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'pro2'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'pro3'
        }
      ]
```

So, if I have another `selected` state. I may have two choices. For example:

Choice1:

```
products[0].selected = true
```

Choice2: use another variable to save the state like:

```
let selectedIndex = 0 //or   let selectedId = 1
```

So, my question is which one is better in most cases?

For example:

`products` is get from backend and may change by pages. And there would be one or more panels to operate the attributes of selected product and send it to server.

Comment: Better in what respect?

Comment: It depends on what you do with it. Choice 2 can prevent to browse the `products` but if you display them all, maybe it is useless! And Choice 2 can be troublesome if the array is editable.

Comment: If your array is static, choice 2 else choice 1

Comment: This is opinion based

Answer (score -1):

If you can select more than 1 product at a time, go for choice #1.

If you can only select 1 product, go for choice #2.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with a variation of Choice 2

**Selected Id**

```
let selectedId = 1
```

This is an improvement over Choice 2 since the selection doesn't depend on the implementation.

If multiple items are to be selected, I would implement an array of selected Ids.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you will display the currently selected product.

If you will display **all** products and highlight the selected, then it's better to use the `.selected = true` approach, because you'll iterate over all products, and it's slightly easier to read the flag than compare `selectedIndex` with current index being iterated.

In the other hand, if you will display only the selected product, the `.selected = true` approach will demand a `products.filter` call, which may be expensive if you have too many products.

Maybe the best option is a mix of both approaches, keep the selected `id` instead of the selected index. This will not only help the `.filter` iteration, but it also will allow you to reorder the products.

Answer (score -1):

With option 1, it is possible to have multiple products selected at the same time, since `product[0].selected` and `product[1].selected` can be true. If that is not intended, you would have to implement some logic that allows only one product to be selected. Things would get complicated quickly... So in that case, option 2 would be better.

On the other hand, if for some reason your usecase is to have multiple products selected at the same time, it would be good to have the attribute directly on the object (option 1) for easy access and maintainability.

TLDR: It depends...